# Bash script to identify file extension in a sub directory and group the parent directors accordingly

Tags: python, node.js, bash

I have 100s of folders that are cloned from Github. Each folder has code that's either in Java, JavaScript, C# or Python. I'm trying to write a script that looks into each of these folders and move them into different folders based on programming languages like below:

**Actual:**

- ParentFolder1

  - Subfolder

    - Sub folder

      - Sub folder
      - ..
        MyFile.java
- ParentFolder2

  - Subfolder

    - Sub folder

      - Sub folder
      - ..
        MyFile2.java
- ParentFolder3

  - Subfolder

    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.js
- ParentFolder4

  - Subfolder

    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.cs

As you can see in the above, somewhere in the subfolders you have files with appropriate extensions like **.java, .js, .cs or .py** and we can use that to know what kind of programming language this Git repo is written in.

**Expected:**

- Java

  - ParentFolder1

    - Subfolder
    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.java
  - ParentFolder2

    - Subfolder
    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.java
- JS

  - ParentFolder3

    - Subfolder
    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.js
- Python

  - ParentFolder3

    - Subfolder
    - Sub folder

      - ..
        MyFile.py

As you can see now that repos are grouped into parent folders based on programming languages.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yea, I tried using Node.js script but its lot more complex that what I originally thought and didnt really work well

Answer (score 0):

Would to try the following:

```
declare -A ext2dir=(["java"]="Java" ["js"]="JS" ["py"]="Python" ["cs"]="CS")
# add pairs of extension and group name according to your files

while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    ext="${f##*.}"              # extracts extension such as "java"
    parent="${f#./}"            # remove leading "./"
    parent="${parent%%/*}"      # extracts parent dirname such as "ParentFolder1"
    [[ -n ${ext2dir[$ext]} ]] && declare -A group[$parent]="${ext2dir[$ext]}"
    # create a map to associate parent dirname (e.g "ParentFolder1") with group name (e.g. "Java")
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.*" -print0)

for parent in "${!group[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "${group[$parent]}"
    mv -- "$parent" "${group[$parent]}"
done
```

- It first invokes `find` to pick up fullpaths of the files which have an extension.
- If the extension is registered in the associative array `ext2dir`, then it maps the parent directory name (such as `ParentFolder1`) to the group name (such as `Java`).
- Finally it moves the parent directories to the group-named directories.
- If your files have more extension types, modify the list of `ext2dir` accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, will try it